# how to allow user input both str and int

Tags: python-3.x

I have a function that is supposed to take a user input both string and int such as (555-GOT-FOOD) and print the correct digit for each string character. How can i get my function to take the user input (555-GOT-EATS)

Code:

def num(n):

```
    chars = []
    for char in n:
            if char.isalpha():
                    if char.lower() in ['A', 'B', 'C']:
                            chars.append('2')
                    elif char.lower() in ['D', 'E', 'F']:
                            chars.append('3')
                    elif char.lower() in ['G', 'H', 'I']:
                            chars.append('4')
                    elif char.lower() in ['J', 'K', 'L']:
                            chars.append('5')
                    elif char.lower() in ['M', 'N', 'O']:
                            chars.append('6')
                    elif char.lower() in ['P', 'R', 'S']:
                            chars.append('7')
                    elif char.lower() in ['T', 'U', 'V']:
                            chars.append('8')
                    else:
                            chars.append('9')
            else:
                    chars.append(char)
    return ''.join(chars)
```

num (555-"got"-"food")

Comment: why are you doing char.lower() and then checking if that is in a list of UPPER? Also why not regex? if you know it starts with a digit r'\d{3,3} ...

Answer (score 0):

Either you take in a char array and convert the first three numbers in to an int afterwards. Alternatlively you can take in a string and after pull out the 3numbers and convert to an int.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting user input, you shouldn't need to worry about the 5's being ints because they aren't ints! Python gets all user input as a string. So they are numbers, yes, but they are of the type string, not int. Think of them as just the symbols representing numbers.

If you modify the end of your code like this,  it should work.

```
                elif char.lower() in ['T', 'U', 'V']:
                        chars.append('8')
                elif char.lower() in ['X', 'Y', 'Z']:
                        chars.append('9')
                else:
                        chars.append(char)
return ''.join(chars)
```

You will also want to use

```
n.replace("-", "")
```

to get rid of all "-", giving you "555GOTFOOD" instead of "555-GOT-FOOD".

Also, I'm not sure if it will work as is, or if you need to change char.lower() to char.upper() since your lists are all upper case letters.